# Create custom number data type within range?

Tags: python, types

In Ada, you can define a custom data type such as this

```
type Day_Of_Month is range 1 .. 31;
```

So now you can create a `Day_Of_Month` variable that can only hold an int between 1 and 31. This is nice because we don't have to keep doing conditional checks when want to update the value, with proper exception handling.

Is there an easy way to do a similar thing in Python?

Comment: Closures or a class that encapsulates the bounds checking are the only two ways I can think of.  There isn't any language feature like this.

Comment: Check out the `datetime` module.  You can create and work with `datetime` objects to accomplish this.

Comment: I think I inadvertently threw people off. The example is just a random one I found online. My code is actually a number that should only be in the range 1..10. Since there isn't an easy way to do this, I'll just stick with conditional checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this datatype is going to get used often, it might be worth creating a class for it and overwriting operators so it works more seamlessly. That way, all the exception handling is still internal to the datatype, and it gives you plenty of flexibility to define things like, for your example, differences in the number of days in February and March, or moving from month to month.

Comment: I don't see how reimplementing `datetime` module could be useful.

Comment: @JF: Granted. I was thinking in a more hypothetical fashion. Indeed, just using the `datetime` module would make the most sense for the listed example.

Answer (score 0):

It is more a comment than an answer:

You could use `datetime` module to work with date and time in Python. It will raise proper exceptions when necessary.

In general if you have data and some invariant that you'd like to keep during certain operations with that data then it is appropriate to create a class that allows you to perform those operations on the data while keeping the invariant.

Note: you don't want to implement a generic arithmetic class that just limits input/output for operations: it is not easy (see [`decimal.Decimal`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/decimal.py), [`fractions.Fraction`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py)) and it is not useful in this case e.g., what is the correct result of:

```
day_of_month + 1
```

To answer it you should know month, year (and timezone sometimes). Thus you begin to implement `datetime` module and `pytz`, `dateutil` packages.